# please I need help, how can one write a controller for the default user content type in strapi

Tags: strapi

I tried this from the docs:
async findOne(ctx) {

```
const { id } = ctx.params;

const entity = await strapi.services.user.findOne({ id });
console.log(entity)
return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.user });
```

},
};

and it gave me this error 'error TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
'

Comment: if user is undefined, then user.findOne will fail. You should check that it is not undefined before calling findOne:
`const entity = await strapi.services.user?.findOne({ id });`